# Unhide and unprotect a workbook, all its worksheets and cells

Tags: ms-office, office-js

Given a workbook, I want to unhide and unprotect the whole workbook including all its sheets, ranges and cells by JavaScript API.

For `unhidding`, I see `visibility` as a property of [Worksheet](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheet), `columnHidden`, `hidden` and `rowHidden` as properties of [Range](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/range). But is there any method to unhide them?

For `unprotecting`, there is `unprotect()` method of [WorksheetProtection](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheetprotection). Will applying this method to all the worksheets be sufficient to unprotect the whole workbook and everything inside?

Comment: Did you give unprotect() a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.visibility` of a worksheet refers to whether the worksheet itself is visible or hidden.

For hiding/unhiding a particular range:  set `columnHidden` to `true` to hide, and `false` to show (unhide).  Same goes for `rowHidden`.

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange().columnHidden = true;
    return ctx.sync();
});
```

For `.unprotect()`, yes, applying it to each worksheet should unprotect it all.

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, Developer on Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Comment: Take a look at the the possible values of Excel.SheetVisiblity.  They are:      `visible`, `hidden`, and `veryHidden`.  So to unhide, set `sheet.visibility = Excel.SheetVisibility.visible;`